# Multiple DHT22 sensors in different sets of GPIO ports

Tags: gpio, dht22

Is it possible to connect multiple sensors to different ports?

I have one working using 1 for 3.3, 9 for GPIO4 and 6 for ground based on this image https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTu-qMk1CqQI2gViyvKvooRGiOfRKgfUBecHp1JJPVbnXTHfqFFM4nyW1QKOw )

Should  I also be able to use 17, 23 and 20 for a 2nd sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  First tend I tried it, I had the sensor plugged in the wrong ports.  So to call via python, you just set the new GPIO port and you can get temps from either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can as suggested by dcole. However its always good to pull connections (vcc and gnd) [image]

If you see the circuit diagram I have marked the `vcc and gnd pins` which are used by many other pins of the lcd. It is always better to reuse the `GPIO pins 1 and 6` instead of going for `GPIO 17 and 20` for `vcc` and `gnd`